# How can I build solution with all the dependency jars

Tags: java, maven, jar, build, ear

I want to distribute my application with all the dependencies. At present I have build it as a `jar` file but then I need to manually copy the some `dependent jars` to `JBOSS`.

I know that I can not put `jars` in side the `jar` but `classes`. But I don't like that solution. So I thought to build an `ear` file. When I read it everywhere it mentioned that it required to have `ejb`, `war` or `web service` component but in my case I only have general class files. Basically no `EJB jar`, `war` or `web service`. So my short question is can I build an `ear` with `Java module` and dependency jars inside the lib folder?

I use Maven as the builder.

Comment: What is your application technically? A web application? An ejb application? If your application contains neither ejbs, nor a webfrontend nor webservices, why would you want to deploy it to an application server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with Maven EAR Plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/

Comment: is it possible to build an ear without ejb, war, web service?

Comment: Hm what are you trying to accomplish? If you want to run it on Jboss it has to be at least a web-/servlet application (so a war)?

Comment: I have some other J2EE modules in Jboss so I want to deploy it inside the Jboss.